# Finding the length of a list at any given index n within an [[Int]] list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

My question might be very simple and elementary, but I feel like there is one crucial thing I've missed so far.

My goal is to compute the length of a list within an `[[Int]]` list, at any given index.

For instance, listLength `[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]] 3` should result in `4`. My function goes as follows

```hs
listLength :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int 
listLength (x:[xs]:[[xxs]]) n = length ((x:[xs]:[[xxs]]) !! n)
```

it compiles too, but whenever I call it with a parameter similar to the one above I get a *Non-exhaustive patterns in function* exception.

What I think I'm missing here is the part where one has to define a suitable pattern for a list with **1)** variable length within the `[[Int]]` list, however, with also **2)** variable length within the `[Int]` lists which the `[[Int]]` list is composed of.

I've tried `x:[xs]` for simulating **2)**, and `[xs]:[[xxs]]` for simulating **1)**. However, I still receive the error that there is no pattern to be matched with.

How could I simulate the preceeding narrative? Any help would be super super appreciated.

Comment: This will only match for a matrix that contains exactly three rows and where the second and third row have exactly *one* element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you seek is... `xss`:

```
listLength :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int 
listLength xss n = length (xss !! n)
```

Note that this uses indices starting from 0, as usual. If you need the indices to start from 1, use `length (xss !! (n-1))` instead.

It is a fairly common error to use a pattern which is too complex only because one feels that working on lists-of-lists requires some special care with respect to only lists. However, that is a red herring. Note the types:

```
xss :: [[Int]]
n :: Int
xss !! n :: [Int]   -- since that's the element type of [[Int]]
length (xss !! n) :: Int
```

Also, there is no need to make a special case for the empty/non-empty list: `length` already handles all cases.

Comment: thank you!!!!! Gosh, you don't know how many hours I spent solving that last night... it finally works... is there any site you could recommend for me maybe to learn more about the pattern differences, like, x, xs, xss? It's so unintuitive!

Comment: @EmmaLee I personally found http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching useful when I was learning Haskell.

Comment: @EmmaLee `xss` is only a variable name, with no special formal meaning. `listLength frog cat = length (frog !! cat) ` would work as well. We like to use `xss` to remind ourselves "this is a list-of-lists", but Haskell does not care.